# Need help with Boolean alg

Tags: boolean-algebra

There's a Boolean algebra which happens:

> For any $y\in B$, if $y+y'=0$ then $y=0$

We need to Refute or prove

Comment: Have you tried trivial Boolean algebras, such as $1$-element or $2$-element Boolean algebras?

Comment: no, I didn't try it

Answer (score 1):

Since $y+y'=1$, the statement is either vacuously true or $B$ is the trivial one-element Boolean algebra.